# How to fix the area inside Elementhost in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, elementhost

I have integrated WPF control in Windows form using ElementHost. The WPF control contains 3D view of an obj file from 3DS Max. When the windows form is resized, the content inside the ElelmentHost displays more than the area specified.

```
<UserControl.Resources> 
   <ImageBrush x:Key="ImageBrush5" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D x:Name="viewport" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">         
       <Viewport3D.Camera>
```

Is it possible to avoid this so that the same area is displayed in different windows size?

Comment: please, show your xaml

Comment: <UserControl.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="ImageBrush5" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Viewport3D x:Name="viewport"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
         <Viewport3D.Camera>

Comment: that's all? and show  code where you put this xaml into `WInForms`?

Comment: Please Refer following URL

http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Docking-WPF-controls-in-the-VSTO-Task-Pane.aspx